# How do I determine the duration of a sample buffer uses in an AVAssetWriter

Tags: ios, buffer, avassetwriter, cmtime, cmsamplebufferref

I have a sample buffer that I'm using to capture video for an AVAssetWriter. I'm trying to figure out a way to determine how much video (time) I have captured. currently I am able to access the current buffer timestamp by using

```
CMTime pts = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
```

I'm looking for a way to determine the duration of the buffer, i've tried

```
CMTime dur = CMSampleBufferGetOutputDuration(sampleBuffer); but it seems to fluctuate
```

between .002333 and nan for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Why not just keep a timestamp for the first sample, and do a very simple calculation (latest timestamp minus the first one)?